# Sublime Text 3 macro to open all files of certain type make some changes and save them?

Tags: sublimetext3

I need to perform certain actions to each file and doing it manually would take a lot of time as there are manny files.

Automating this somehow would be very helpful.

Can this be done with Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime macros cannot open or close groups of files, you would have to specify the exact filename of each file you want to manipulate. To do what you are asking would probably require a Python plugin instead. You can use its pattern-matching capabilities to open whatever you want (or just feed it a list of files), then it can execute [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) commands, built-in editor commands, or simply wait for you to make the changes manually before saving, closing, and moving on to the next file. Essentially, any Sublime menu option can be automated, and new commands built up using the API and pure Python.